# How do I have an MVC6 custom model binder call the default model binder for a specific model property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC6 controller I have a model that I want to bind to that looks a bit like

```
public class RequestWrapper
{
    public IRequest Request { get; set; }
}
```

The purpose of this is to allow a single controller action to instantiate certain types of requests, so I can go to the url `/api/Invoke/DoSomethingRequest?UserId=55`.

My custom model binder will then pull out the `DoSomethingRequest`, match it with the actual C# class called `DoSomethingRequest`, create an instance of the `DoSomethingRequest` class, populate the `DoSomethingRequest.UserId` property, then return that the completed model.

I have the first part of that done, the problem is I don't want to reimplement the model binding to bind all of `DoSomethingRequest`'s properties.

How would I go about piggy backing on the the default model binding systems after my custom model binder creates an instance of an object?